# Using a CompositeItemWriter that has JdbcBatchItemWriters to write different object types to different tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a nested object like this where the datasource is the same. However, I need to write to different tables. Here is the structure of my object. Is this possible?

```
  class Project {
      ProjectItem projectItem;
      ItemOwner owner;
  }
  @Bean 
  JdbcBatchItemWriter projectItemWriter(DataSource datasource){
      return new JdbcBatchItemWriter<ProjectItem> {
      ... etc
  }
  
  @Bean 
  JdbcBatchItemWriter itemOwnerWriter(DataSource datasource){
      return new JdbcBatchItemWriter<ItemOwner> {
      ... etc
  }
  
   @Bean
   CompositeItemWriter<Project> txnWriter() {
    return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Department>()
            .delegates(projectItemWriter(null),
                    itemOwnerWriter(null))
            .build();
  }
```

My use case is unique as I need to somehow write to different tables based on the object type. Is this possible. and if so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a JPA solution instead. I needed to write all the nested items so I chose to use JPA